# What is the best approach to autolayout dynamic size uitableview cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, autolayout

I am currently stucked trying to create a uitableview cell with autolayouting that dynamically resizes according to the "Dynamic sized labels" within

my approach is subclass the uitableview cell and in the "updateConstraints" method i override :

```
CGFloat width = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width;
[self.contentView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.contentView
                                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                    toItem:nil
                                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                                multiplier:1
                                                                constant:width]];
CGFloat height = self.frame.size.height;
[self.contentView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.contentView
                                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                    toItem:nil
                                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                                multiplier:1
                                                                  constant:height]];;

[super updateConstraints];
```

at the same time i did all the layouting in the nib file where subviews are resized correctly but the cell height doesnot resize.

what is the newbie mistake i am doing here?

Comment: What iOS version are you targeting? Also, edit the question so we can read the code you posted a little easier.

Comment: Have you read [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/73602/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-auto-layout)? It's a great site for newbies.

Comment: i am targeting iOS 7

Answer (score 0):

apparently i was sleeping or something just change

```
[self.contentView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.contentView
                                                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                             relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationGreaterThanOrEqual
                                                                toItem:nil
                                                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                            multiplier:1
                                                              constant:height]];;
```